# Why are some classes not public in the Android Support Library?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-design-library

Why are some of the classes included in Android's Libraries not public? To me this makes no real sense and basically just introduces a barrier to developing temporary fixes to some of the bug-riddled widgets that have recently been released.

Specifically I'm talking about the `TextInputLayout` in the [**Android Design Support Library**](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).
For example if I want to make a custom widget which overrides some of the code in the constructor I can't do that because `CollapsingTextHelper` is not a public class. I would have to download the source code and copy the relevant classes to my project, but there isn't really anything that is preventing me from doing that anyway. So what's the point of not making it public in the first place?

As I understand it as a library gets updated and improved over time you can just add the `@Deprecated` annotation to indicate that a specific class is old or outdated and is only still around to prevent legacy code from breaking.
I know that it makes no sense for a library to simply make all classes public, but I don't understand why classes essential to the implementation of a widget shouldn't be public. Why can't they just add the `@Deprecated` annotation when one of the classes is replaced by a better version, or when widgets are implemented in a different way altogether?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  This could be interpreted as broadly as asking what are the advantages of OO encapsulation.

Comment: Are you trying to make a custom widget but you do not want to extend from the android widget class? (you accidentally wrote super class, it should be sub class). Why would you not want to extend from the widget class? Any reason?

Comment: I editted my question to hopefully clear up what I was really asking. If it's still confusing or unclear then maybe my question is just really dumb. But at least I'll know why you know

Comment: It's about more than just a class becoming deprecated. If the inner workings of a widget are not public Google can completely change the implementation without having to mark classes as deprecated. They can remove and add classes and change everything about them without having to worry about maintaining backwards compatibility. If a third party developer wants to use some of the non public classes he can do that pretty easily anyway. In Android Studio or IntelliJ you can view the source code of the support library with one click/hotkey and copy it to your own project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short - by making those classes non-public they're reserving the right to change/delete this class at any time without breaking any client's (your) code.

Look at how many `@Deprecated` methods/classes there are already and you'll see why this is important.

Comment: I edited my post with my response to this. Can you let me know your thoughts?

Comment: @Solarnum problem with deprecation is that even though you can annotate class as `Deprecated` and just write new one from scratch you still **have** to support the old version, since legacy code will still depend on it. Of course, it's not something you can't do. But if you'll repeat this procedure over and over again, your codebase will just become a mess. Another reason for non-public classes (in particular, package-private ones) is that they usually contain some tricky logic which requires deep knowledge of underlying framework (which can also change) - this is especially true for UI

Comment: @Solarnum comment for your question by Xaver Kapeller is also very good. Consider reading it

Comment: I've never really thought about it before because the only times I've ever personally encountered non-public classes (other than with TextInputLayout) have been with system level classes in android and I didn't give it a second thought because it just makes sense that they would be inaccessible.

Answer (score 3):

Once you add a public class to your library you basically have to maintain it. You cannot simply remove it because that would be a breaking change. As a result you can only mark it as `@Deprecated` and continue to maintain it far longer than you actually have a use for it.

---

**But** it's about more than just a class becoming deprecated. Mainly I am talking about the difference between API and implementation details.

If the inner workings of a widget are not public Google can completely change the implementation without having to mark any of those classes as deprecated. This has multiple advantages in the long run.

They can remove and add classes and change everything about them without having to worry about maintaining backwards compatibility. If a third party developer wants to use some of the non public classes he or she can do that pretty easily anyway.

In Android Studio or IntelliJ you can view the source code of the support library with simply by right clicking on the class and selecting `"Go to" -> "Declaration"` or with these shortcuts:

- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

From there on out it is pretty simple to copy the relevant classes to your project, modify them and use them however you like.

---

Suffice it say that in 99% of all cases you are not going to need to do that anyway. Google surely put a lot of thought into which classes should be public and as a result are part of the API and which are just part of the implementation of a widget.

Comment: You can also ⌘+Click a class name and it will take you to the source doc. Thanks! I guess what I was just thinking is that instead of making classes non-public there could just be an annotation like @Unsupported or something but that's a pretty niche use case for something that would need to be used broadly with an easy manual work around haha..... So everything is making sense.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason every other class/field/variable in java (and not only) has access modifiers.

If it's not public you are not meant to use it (same rules apply to other modifiers depending on the context; encapsulation etc.).

It's probably there in order to enchance or help the library's esoteric function.

For a specific answer please make your question less broad. Which class did you want to use that wasn't public and you thought it should be?